# How to rename a package and it subpackages in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I have a project with the following package structure in IntelliJ:

```
com.example.api --> has classes inside of it
com.example.api.foo --> has classes inside of it 
com.example.api.bar --> has classes inside of it
```

When I refactor rename `com.example.api` to `come.other.api` I end up with package structure below:

```
com.other.api
com.example.api.foo
com.example.api.bar
```

I am expecting IntelliJ to rename the subpackages too, but it is not I have played around with a bunch of the options in the IntelliJ refactor rename dialog box but no luck. If I refactor rename starting with the leaf packages everything works.

I am not sure if I am dealing with a bug in IntelliJ or they changed something in the UI and its is user error. I am on IntelliJ 2023.3.3.

Comment: I don't have this problem in 2023.3.3. What view is selected in the Project window in your case? ("Project", "Tests", "Packages", etc. )

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch the view for the packages to turn off the flatten packages then I cloud click on the top level package and do a refactor rename and it worked. I have been coding in java since 2004 and I have done this type of refactor 100s or 1000s of times not sure why the latest version of IntelliJ is so broken / counter intutive UI

[image]